# Determine if an SQLite row does not exist in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sqlite

No solutions I have found in my searches fixed this problem.  I am attempting to make a simple quote-storing program in SQLite3.  The following code works when I enter a quote id that does exist:

```
app.get('/quote/:id', function(req, res) {
if (exists) {
    db.serialize( function() {
        db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, text, author FROM quotes WHERE rowid = " + req.params.id, function(err, row) {
            if (row != null && row != undefined && row != []) {
                return res.send("Text: '" + row.text + "'<br>Author: " + row.author);
                console.log("Found that match!");
                match = true;
            }
            else {
                return res.send("Error 404!")
            }
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
}
else if (req.params.id < quotes.length && req.params.id >= 0) {
    res.send(quotes[req.params.id]);
    console.log("taking from the offline database");
}
});
```

but when I enter an id that doesn't exist, instead of showing the Error 404, the page just keeps loading until it times out.  I believe the problem may be that the db.each function does not get called at all if the desired row does not exist, but how do I fix this?  Is it possible to check whether something exists and then display a 404 if not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible to execute a separate query using EXISTS or COUNT.

But if you want to ensure that your callback always gets called, add another row to the query:

```sql
SELECT id, text, author FROM ... WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL
LIMIT 1;
```

(The [LIMIT clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#limitoffset) omits the NULL row when some data *is* found.)

Comment: Thank you so much!  This worked like a charm when I changed `if (row != null)` to `if (row.text != null)`!!